# Switch $resource to variable in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

What i need is switch from AJAX to global VARIABLE and apply all functions.

Object json_in_html is declared in html and i need to replace tempObj with it. Unfortunately it isn't accesible in the same manner like $response object because Angular adding additional function to it. How can i do this switch?

**Working code:**

```
var tempObj = API.getMedia(function() {
            for (var obj in tempObj)
                tempObj[obj].acf && tempObj[obj].acf.is_gallery && tempObj[obj].acf.galerie && ((tempObj[obj].acf.galerie[0] == attrs.gallery || tempObj[obj].acf.galerie[1] == attrs.gallery) && scope.gallery.push(tempObj[obj]));
            $timeout(function() {
                $element.imagesLoaded().always(function(instance) {
                    $element.isotope({
                        itemSelector: "img",
                        layoutMode: "masonry"
                    })
                }).done(function(instance) {}).fail(function() {
                    console.log("all images loaded, at least one is broken")
                }).progress(function(instance, image) {
                    $(image.img).addClass("active"),
                    $("img.preloader").removeClass("show")
                })
            }, 1e3)
        });
```

**Not working:**

```
var tempObj = json_in_html;
            for (var obj in tempObj)
                tempObj[obj].acf && tempObj[obj].acf.is_gallery && tempObj[obj].acf.galerie && ((tempObj[obj].acf.galerie[0] == attrs.gallery || tempObj[obj].acf.galerie[1] == attrs.gallery) && scope.gallery.push(tempObj[obj]));

            //$timeout - THIS ISN'T EXIST
            $timeout(function() {

                //$element - THIS ISN'T EXIST
                $element.imagesLoaded().always(function(instance) {
                    $element.isotope({
                        itemSelector: "img",
                        layoutMode: "masonry"
                    })
                //.done- THIS ISN'T EXIST
                }).done(function(instance) {}).fail(function() {
                    console.log("all images loaded, at least one is broken")
                //.progress - THIS ISN'T EXIST
                }).progress(function(instance, image) {
                    $(image.img).addClass("active"),
                    $("img.preloader").removeClass("show")
                })
            }, 1e3)
```

**Where I stuck (I assume that JSON is ready becasue is in html so no need to wait for data):**

```
var tempObj = json_in_html;
            for (var obj in tempObj)
                tempObj[obj].acf && tempObj[obj].acf.is_gallery && tempObj[obj].acf.galerie && ((tempObj[obj].acf.galerie[0] == attrs.gallery || tempObj[obj].acf.galerie[1] == attrs.gallery) && scope.gallery.push(tempObj[obj]));

                    //ERROR - How to create $element object from JSON?
                    $element.isotope({
                        itemSelector: "img",
                        layoutMode: "masonry"
                    })

                    //ERROR - How to access image object from this scope?
                    $(image.img).addClass("active"),
                    $("img.preloader").removeClass("show")
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What does "switch $resource to variable" mean? Can you give a clear example of what is happening vs what you expect to happen, any errors you see, and what part of the code is problematic? This is quite dense as it is.

Comment: Thanks. I aded examples so it is more clear where is problem.